# How do you use buffers/panes? Possible to move a buffer into another pane?

Tags: neovim, buffers, window-management

I recently switched from VsCode and I am quite confused about the window/pane system of neovim.

It seems like these are the only options to actually use panes in neovim:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4571319/9168173

But all these options just switch and move the panes itself.
I'd like to move the buffer into a new pane instead. Consider this example:

Panes A B C

Files 1 2 3

what if i just want to move File 1 to Pane B?

I consider Panes as stack of files/buffers.

Lets say i've File 1 open on Pane A and open File 4 on top of it.
If i move now File 4 to Pane B, i would end up with this:

Panes A B C

Files 1 4 3

since there is still File 1 on the Stack of Pane A. Is this behaviour even possible in vim/neovim?

Comment: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-buffers/ http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-windows/ http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Files" (called buffers in Vim documentation) are not associated to "Panes" (called windows in Vim documentation).

To have buffer 4 to window B you could:

- Go to window B and
- Open buffer 4 (`:b 4`)

To move buffer through windows you could be interested to look at the [winresizer](https://github.com/simeji/winresizer) plugin that let you move buffer across windows using the `h`, `j`, `k` and `l` keys.

With the plugin you have to:

1. Activate [winresizer](https://github.com/simeji/winresizer) with <kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> and
2. Switch to buffer move mode with <kbd>e</kbd>
3. Use the `h`, `j`, `k` and `l` keys to move the current buffer across windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At least i know now from a knowledgeable person whats possible and what isn't. Maybe i'll create my own plugins, to enable stack-based window management - i'll see

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Welcome to Vim :-)